# Jmeter Pass Regular Expression to teh regex extract via datasource

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have the below regex extract steps part of my request.

[image]

[image]

I am trying to pass the actual expression from the datasource file

[image]

and when verfying using the dummy sampler, the expression for ADDRESS_LOC_ID works successfully, where as the second extract ADDRESS_LOC_LABEL which has the expression - "id":${ADDRESS_LOC_ID},"label":"([\w ]+)", it fails.

But running with passsing the expression directly and not via the datasource works well and has no issues.

Dummy sampler Output  - directly passing the expression in the extract

[image]

Dummy sampler output - ​when passing the expression via datasource

[image]

Response Body (the extrcat being used on) - [{"id":12176,"label":"512 Uranium Street Broken Hill NSW 2880","value":"512 Uranium Street Broken Hill NSW 2880"}]

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what do you want from us.

> If it compiles, it is good; if it boots up, it is perfect.“
>
> — Linus Torvalds

As long as the solution works for you it's "is right".

The only piece of advice I can give you is stop using Beanshell, [since JMeter 3.1 users are encouraged to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting in particular and it's also recommended to avoid scripting and use JMeter's built-in test elements in general, for example variables could be visualized using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) combination.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri. I realized it was vague. I have used the dummy sampler as suggested and have reiterated my question accrodingly. hope it makes sense now.

Comment: If you're keeping references to JMeter Variables in a file you need to use [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) in order to perform the substitution. More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)